# Unable to install 'Java Platform, Enterprise Edition 7 (with JDK 7u45)'

Tags: macos, java

I have downloaded an [java j2ee and jdk installer from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-7-sdk-with-jdk-u45-2066865.html)

[image]

When I run it I got this error message:

```
$ ./java_ee_sdk-7-jdk7-macosx-x64-ml.sh
Extracting the installer archive...
Extracing bundled JDK...

Could not locate a suitable Java runtime.
Please ensure that you have Java 7 or newer installed on your system
and accessible in your PATH or by setting JAVA_HOME
```

At the moment I have only got java 6 in my MBP (running OSX 10.9.4).

I would have expected the installer is smart enough to run from the unpacked bundled JDK.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Enterprise Edition of the JDK does not contain the JRE -- you have to install that stand alone first and only then install the JDK as detailed here :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have installed the JRE 1.7 successfully (plugin in safari is tested ok) but I can't access the new java command in the shell. Do you have any more info/pointer?

Comment: I have figured it out. I have to install the Java SDK. The java_ee_sdk-7-jdk7-macosx-x64-ml.sh package has a dependency of `jar` which is not available in JRE.